# How do I fix line numbers disappearing in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I've been having a weird issue with Atom: Sometimes, the numbers of the lines just disappear. It is permanent as it stays on the same lines after closing and reopening the software.

I've also deleted the `.atom` folder in my home directory so the software starts from scratch, but it didn't change anything. Does anyone know where that could come from?

[image: Screenshot of the bug]